# Restriction of an $n$-form to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

I am currently studying exterior calculus on manifolds and am not sure if I understand things correctly. In my textbook (R.W.R. Darling, Differential Forms and Connections) there is an example of a $2$-form on $A:=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$, namely

$$\omega = \frac{x(dy\wedge dz) - y(dx\wedge dz)+z(dx\wedge dy)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}.$$

Now restricting $\omega$ to the unit sphere $S^2$ gives a $2$-form $\eta\in\Omega^2S^2$ and some calculations show that $d\eta = 0$.

The example ends here, and I am wondering: Does this imply that also $d\omega = 0$? Otherwise I do not see why the author would start with a $2$-form on $A$ (also, I have a similar homework assignment which deals with a similar 2-dimensional case and where $d\omega = 0$ is to be verified on the whole set $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$). My ideas are the following:

The map $g \colon A \to S^2, g((x,y,z)) := \frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ is smooth, and (according to the textbook) the pullback of $g$ is a linear map $g^* \colon \Omega^qS^2 \to \Omega^qA$  satisfying $g^*d\alpha = d(g^*\alpha)$ for all differential forms $\alpha$ (I believe this textbook notation of its domain and range is a bit sloppy; $g^*$ is meant to be a map assigning any differential form a differential form of one higher degree). Now if I understand the meaning of the pullback correctly, it holds $g^*\eta = \omega$, hence the above equation applied on the $2$-form $\eta$ implies that $0 = g^*0 = g^*d\eta = d(g^*\eta) = d\omega$.

Is this argumentation correct? Is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: Why do you need to do calculations to show that a $2$ form on $S^2$ is closed? It's a top-dimensional form, there are no $3$-forms on a $2$-manifold. Certainly you can do the same thing for another $2$-form, take $zdx\wedge dy$ this restricts to a $2$-form on $S^2$ which is closed (because all $2$ forms on a $2$-manifold are) but clearly it has a non-vanishing exterior derivative, and so is not closed as a member of $\Lambda^2(\Bbb R^3\setminus\mathbf{0})$.

Comment: I have corrected two wrong statements that the dimension of the starting form $\omega$ equals $1$; it should be $2$.

Comment: The second-last paragraph is confusing. Any $n$-form on an $n$-manifold is closed. Further, your $\omega$ is closed as a $2$-form on $A$ by a direct computation (using derivatives etc)

Comment: That $2-$form is closed in $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{{\bf 0}\}$. It is a particular case of the form studied in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764931/prove-the-exterior-derivative-of-the-following-n-1-form-is-zero/1764946#1764946).

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you, that example makes sense. I did not know that there cannot be $n+1$-forms on an $n$-manifold. The calculations were shown in the textbook, probably then just to show how exterior calculus works on manifolds.

Comment: @PeterFranek yeah, $M$ was not meant to be of dimension $n$, that was confusing I guess. So the statement was meant for a $n$-form on a differential $m$-manifold, so to say. However, as Adam Hughes pointed out, that is not true.

Comment: So the usual way to show that $d\omega = 0$ would be by direct computation, using only the properties of the exterior derivative? And how about my ideas with the pullback, did they make any sense?

Comment: There are many ways how to show $d\omega=0$ but in this case, a direct computation is easy (it's just one short line of text, including elementary derivatives). No, I don't think the argument with submanifolds makes any sense. The pullback of *any* $n$-form to an $n$-manifold will be closed, no matter whether the form is closed or not. Moreover, you didn't impose any constraints on the $n$-submanifold $P$, so $P$ could be the empty set. You cannot argue like that.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did the calculation, it was easier than I expected, so my question became unneccessary. Anway now I have a little more insight in those structures. I just deleted the question on the generalization, since it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you've got it backwards. :)

Let $i : S^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the usual inclusion. If $\omega$ is a form on $\Bbb R^3$, then its restriction to $S^2$ is *defined* as $\eta = i^* \omega$ (the pull-back of $\omega$). Therefore, the fact that $\eta$ is closed does not mean anything relevant for $\omega$ because $0 = \Bbb d \eta = \Bbb d (i^* \omega) = i^* (\Bbb d \omega)$ and...? You can't get $\Bbb d \omega = 0$ from this.

What you are doing with your map $g$ is that instead of *pulling* $\omega$ *back* (as I have done above), you are *pushing* it *forward*. The problem is that the push-forward $g_*$ is defined only when $g$ is an injective immersion - clearly not the case here. So not only are you doing a push-forward (instead of a pull-back), but you are also doing it wrong! :)

What you denote $g^* \eta$ is *not* the restriction of $\omega$ to $S^2$, it's just some form on $\Bbb R^3$. In particular, it is not true that $g^* \eta = \omega$.